# ruby Datamapper is not inserting all records

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have this ruby function which yields 1095 records `MusicTab::FOps.gen_list('/fun/Music')`
and I want to store them using datamapper. When I do this

```
MusicTab::FOps.gen_list('/fun/Music') do |arr_f|
@files=Files.create(
:file_path => arr_f[0],
:title => arr_f[1],
:album => arr_f[2],
:artist => arr_f[3] )
end
```

only 154 records are inserted, I don't understand what is so special about these records.
If I do this I get nil for p @files.id all the other records other than those 154 records which gets stored.

```
MusicTab::FOps.gen_list('/fun/Music') do |arr_f|
@files=Files.create(
:file_path => arr_f[0],
:title => arr_f[1],
:album => arr_f[2],
:artist => arr_f[3] )
p @files.id
p @files.title
p @files.album
end
```

If I just print the values I can see all the values like

```
counter=0
MusicTab::FOps.gen_list('/fun/Music') do |arr_f|
p arr_f
counter=counter+1
end
counter
```

please help..
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking at @files.errors.  My guess is that you are failing a validation and it isn't getting saved.

You can try enabling some Debug logging and see if that helps to isolate the problem.

```
DataMapper::Logger.new($stdout, :debug)
```

It would be helpful to see your Model Definition for the Files object, and a sample of the data that doesn't get saved, and one that does.  The last time I ran into this issue was when  I needed to set the size on my text fields as I was overflowing the default.

Comment: thanks outputing @files.errors showed the error that file_path must be 50 charecters long, in most cases its larger than 50, so can u tell me how to increase the `String` size to may be upto 300 or 500 charecters?